# Cannot reference a component schema defined in a separate file in Swagger

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0, swagger-3.0

I have the following api documentation:

```
swagger: "3.0"
info:
  version: 0.0.1
  title: Test API
paths:
  /users:
    get:
      summary: Get all registered users
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: Users successfully returned
        403:
          description: User not authorised to call this API
          schema:
            $ref: 'components.yaml#/components/schemas/AuthError'
```

Where the AuthError schema is defined in a separate yaml file called components.yaml:

```
components:
  schemas:
    AuthError:
      type: object
      properties:
        error:
          type: sting
          description: Error message
```

And the Swagger configurations:

```
const swaggerDefinition = {
  info: {
    title: 'FlexiWAN REST API documentation',
    version: '1.0.0',
    description: 'This is the REST API for FlexiWAN management',
  },
  components: {},
  host: 'local.flexiwan.com:3443',
  basePath: '/api',
  securityDefinitions: {
    JWT: {
        type: 'apiKey',
        in: 'header',
        name: 'Authorization',
        description: "",
    }
  }

};
const options = {
  swaggerDefinition,
  apis: ['./swagger/**/*.yaml'],
};

const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(options);
app.use('/docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec));
```

But when I try to access Swagger UI I get the following error:

Resolver error at paths./users.get.responses.403.schema.$ref
Could not resolve reference: Tried to resolve a relative URL, without having a basePath. path: 'components.yaml' basePath: 'undefined'

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does it work if you use `$ref: './components.yaml##/components/schemas/AuthError'`? Do you use Swagger UI or Swagger Editor?

Comment: @Helen I changed it according to your suggestions, but it still gives me the same error. I am using Swagger UI via a node package of the same name

Comment: 1) What version of Swagger UI? Can you post your Swagger UI config code? 2) Replace `swagger: "3.0"` with `swagger: "2.0"`

Comment: @Helen my apologies, I'm using swagger UI express package. I edited the post above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I managed to solve this using [this great resource](https://azimi.me/2015/07/16/split-swagger-into-smaller-files.html):

All I had to do is to add a reference to the components at the end of the API documentation file, and change the schema reference accordingly:

```
  403:
    description: User not authorised to call this API
    schema:
      $ref: '#components/schemas/AuthError'

components:
  $ref: './components.yaml'
```

Comment: I doubted if this is a solution to the real problem. I have a similar scenario to yours and tried your suggestion as well, but it did not work. Honestly, I am still not sure if what I've done is correct or not.